# "The procedure entry point XXXX could not be located in the dynamic link library YYYY" after migrating application from BDS 2006 to Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, entry-point, bpl

I have an application developed in BDS 2006 and am migrating it to Delphi 2007. I have packages to install. I am able to build the packages, install them, and generate the EXE and DLLs.

But while running the application, I am getting this error:

> **Entry Point Not Found**
> The procedure entry point XXXX could not be located in the dynamic link library YYYY.
>
> [image: Error while running the EXE]

By using Dependency Walker, I figured out dependant DLLs and they are in place.

Please help me to resolve this error. I would like to know the exact reason why this error is happening.

Comment: Note that the filename.bpl is still part of the error message, as is the window title.

Comment: Seams like you have some old version of BPL file and your project try to use it. Try to remove all old versions from directory with EXE and from other places in Path enviroment variable.

Comment: BPL files are version specific, which means that a BPL compiled with BDS 2006 cannot be used in Delphi 2007 without being recompiled with that newer Delphi version. Either you've not yet done so, or you still have an older version located in your app folder or the system PATH that is being loaded instead.

Comment: @KenWhite Few projects are required to have .bpls in my project for e.g vcl.bpl and rtl.bpl. What I did is I removed these .bpls from the required list from the project and added new .bpls from the Delphi 2007 installed lib location. 

But still problem exists.

In this environment, I didnt install BDS 2006, I believe there is no chance to have the trace of old version bpls

Comment: The BPL listed in the error message is not standard Delphi, which means you are using at least one BPL that could have an old version installed. I don't think you're looking at things carefully enough.

Comment: Do a search of your entire computer for the BPL listed in the error message. If it finds more than one, then one of them is outdated. If it finds only one, that one is mismatched in version and needs to be rebuilt.